# What is the proper Vim/Ag g:ctrlp_user_command value for Windows?

Tags: vim, ctrlp, ag

I would like to fill in the `elsif` in the portion of my `.vimrc` below, can anyone help me with the correct Windows syntax?

```
if executable( 'ag' )
    if has( 'unix' )
        let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor -g ""'
    elsif has( 'win32' )
        " ?
    endif
endif
```

The Unix version is not working in my Windows gvim.

Comment: Looks from the docs like this is operator error on my part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one. Works for me. `let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag -l --nocolor -g "" %s'`

Answer (score 10):

In addition to @amos's answer, you could actually make a bit more addition to use ag in CtrlP as mentioned [here:](https://github.com/bibstha/dotfiles-1/blob/master/vimrc#L65-L75)

```
" Use The Silver Searcher https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher
if executable('ag')
  " Use Ag over Grep
  set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor

  " Use ag in CtrlP for listing files. Lightning fast and respects .gitignore
  let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor -g ""'

  " ag is fast enough that CtrlP doesn't need to cache
  let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0
endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Up-rated, though giving amos the courtesy of the check for being earliest.